# xslt: for-each not working returning 0 results

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been looking at this for too long, I think I'm just missing something simple. My style sheet isn't working, it's not returning any values. I think it's got something to do with namespaces. If I remove them it works as expected.

Below is my XML (abbreviated) and my xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ImportMapping.xslt" ?>
    <ArrayOfSysDefinitionBase xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <SysDefinitionBase xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Scribe.Core.Mapping.AdvSys" i:type="d2p1:AdvSysDefinition">
        <d2p1:BlocksDict xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
          <d3p1:KeyValueOfguidBlocknKIEa0o7>
            <d3p1:Value xmlns:d5p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Scribe.Core.Mapping.AdvSys.Shapes" i:type="d5p1:UpdateInsertBlock">
              <d5p1:FieldMappings xmlns:d6p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Scribe.Core.Mapping.Sys">
                <d6p1:MapBinding>
                  <d6p1:TargetField>createdbyname</d6p1:TargetField>
                  <d6p1:TargetFormula>createdbyname</d6p1:TargetFormula>
                  <d6p1:TargetDataType i:nil="true" />
                </d6p1:MapBinding>
              </d5p1:FieldMappings>
            </d3p1:Value>
          </d3p1:KeyValueOfguidBlocknKIEa0o7>
        </d2p1:BlocksDict>
      </SysDefinitionBase>
    </ArrayOfSysDefinitionBase>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="ArrayOfSysDefinitionBase/SysDefinitionBase">
    <html>
      <body>
      <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Source</th>
            <th>Target</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="BlocksDict/KeyValueOfguidBlocknKIEa0o7/Value/FieldMappings/MapBinding">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="TargetField"/>
              </td>
              <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="TargetFormula"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Looks like a namespace issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it's got something to do with namespaces.

Yes, it has.  Your XML document has many of its elements in various namespaces but your XPath expressions target elements that are not in a namespace.  You need to copy the namespace declarations from the XML into your stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Scribe.Core.Mapping.AdvSys"
                xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
                xmlns:d5p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Scribe.Core.Mapping.AdvSys.Shapes"
                xmlns:d6p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Scribe.Core.Mapping.Sys">
```

and use the appropriate prefixes in the XPaths.

```
<xsl:for-each select="d2p1:BlocksDict/d3p1:KeyValueOfguidBlocknKIEa0o7/d3p1:Value/d5p1:FieldMappings/d6p1:MapBinding">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="d6p1:TargetField"/>
    </td>
    <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="d6p1:TargetFormula"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```